# JMS Topic sender is throwing exception Null pointer exception for the connection Factory

Tags: nullpointerexception, annotations, jms

I am trying to make a simple JMS topic sender.In the code its returning error in the very first line ,where I am creating a connection using ConnectionFactory.

```
public class TopicSender {

@Resource(lookup = "ConnectionFactoryTest1")
private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
@Resource(lookup ="myTopic")
private static Topic topic;

public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException{
    //Create a connection
    Connection connection =connectionFactory.createConnection();
    //Get a session
    Session session =connection.createSession();

    MessageProducer producer=session.createProducer(topic);
    //Send a test message to the topic
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setText("This test message sent at" + new Date());

    producer.send(message);

    session.close();
    connection.close();

}
```

Console output:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.aman.JMS.Test1.TopicSender.main(TopicSender.java:23)
```

Can anybody help me understand why I am getting this exception.
I am using GlassFish server.

Comment: Could it be, that `topic` is `null`, but `session.createProducer` or something doesn't like that?

Comment: It doesn't  even reach that line of code, the exception occurred at the very first line in the main function.

Comment: OK, I see. I think this is a problem with your framework for dependency injection in that case. Sorry - I don't think I can help with that because I haven't used it anywhere so far.